# Octave: is it allowed to have a for() cycle in a function definition?

Tags: function, for-loop, octave, ode

I have a function func() definition which contains a for() cycle.

Can I then pass func() to lsode() to be resolved as an ODE?

Update: Example of the code.

```
int = [0; 0];
slp = [0; 1];
x = [1:10];
r = zeros(1,10);
for id = 1 : 2;
 r = r + int(id) + slp(id)*x;
end
plot(x,r);
function ydot = fnc(y, t, int, slp)
 ydot = zeros(1,10);
 for jd = 1 : 2;
  ydot = ydot + int(jd) + slp(jd)*t;
 end
end
p = lsode(@(y,t) fnc(y,t,int,slp), 1, x);
```

error: lsode: inconsistent sizes for state and derivative vectors
error: called from:
error:   /path$/test_for_function.m at line 15, column 3

Comment: Then debug your program and determine the shape of the state and derivative vectors, in the main if they are row or column vectors. Both should be the same. You could add a print statement in `fnc` for the shape of `y` and `ydot`.

Comment: Did you want to pass `r` as initial value? That should be `p = lsode(@(y,t) fnc(y,t,int,slp), r, x);`. Does the error change with that correction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message has nothing to do with the computations inside the ODE functions. It is telling you that the shape of `ydot` is incompatible with the shape of the state vector that is established by the initial value vector.

First I can not identify in your code example the initial value vector. You seem to construct the array `r` for that, but you pass the scalar constant `1`.

And then it could be as simple as switching the shape dimensions in the construction of `ydot`. Or use `ỳdot = zeros_like(y)` or similar if available.

Comment: I should have explained better, 'r' is to check that the 'for' cycle works as intended. The initial value should be 'y(1) = 0'

Comment: Your differential equation is scalar? From your code it looks like it is a 10-dimensional system.

Comment: I'm afraid the issue is not clear. Why would it be a 10-dimensional system? Isn't the initial condition one scalar per ODE?

Comment: Because `ydot = zeros(1,10);` declares a 10-dimensional vector. The dimension is nowhere changed, all scalars are duplicated to fit this dimension.

Comment: I think I'm getting it. I'll try some tinkering and debugging later.

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging, tinkering and thinking about how `lsode` works, I found how to make my code work as intended:

```
%Start code
int = [0; 0];
slp = [0; 1];
x = [1:10];
for id = 1 : 2;
 r = int(id) + slp(id)*x;
end   %A complicated way to draw a line
 figure(1); clf(1); 
 plot(x,r);
 hold on;
function ydot = fnc(y, t, int, slp)
 for jd = 1 : 2;
  ydot = [int(jd) + slp(jd)*t];
 end
end
p = lsode(@(y,t) fnc(y,t,int,slp), 1, x);
 plot(x, p, '-r');
%EOF
```

And the result is:
[image]

As it should be.